# Filtering grouped data in R

Tags: r, excel, filter, dataframe

I was wondering if anyone can help with grouping the data below as I'm trying to use the subset function to filter out volumes below a certain threshold but given that the data represents groups of objects, this creates the problem of removing certain items that should be kept.

In Column F ( and I) you can see Blue, Red, and Yellow Objects. Each represent three separate colored probes on one DNA strand. Odd numbered or non-numbered Blue ,Red, and Yellow are paired with a homologous strand represented by an even numbered Blue, Red, and Yellow. Ie data in rows 2,3,and 4 are one "group" and pair with the "group" shown in rows 5,6,and 7. This then repeats, so  8,9,10 are a new group and that group pairs with the one in 11,12,13.

What I would like to do is subset the groups so that only those below a certain Distance to Midpoint (column M) are kept. The Midpoint here is the midpoint of the line that connects the blue of one group with the blue of its partner, so the subset should only apply to the Blue distance to midpoint, and that is where I'm having a problem. For instance if I ask to keep blue distances to midpoint that are less than 3, then the objects in row 3 and 4 should be kept because they are part of the group with the blue distance below 3. Right now though when I filter with the subset function I lose Red Selection and Yellow Selection. I'm confident there is a straighforward solution to this in R, but I'd also be open to some type of filtering in excel if anyone has suggestions via that route instead.

EDIT
 I managed to work something out in Excel last night after posting the question. Solution isn't pretty but it works well enough. I just added a new column next to "distance to midpoint" that gives all the objects in one group the same distance so that when I filter the data I won't lose any objects that I shouldn't. If it helps anyone in the future, the formula I used in excel was:

```
     =SQRT ( ((INDEX($B$2:$B$945,1+QUOTIENT(ROWS(B$2:B2)-1,3)*3))-   (INDEX($O$2:$O$945,1+QUOTIENT(ROWS(O$2:O2)-1,3)*3)) ) ^2 +(  (INDEX($C$2:$C$945,1+QUOTIENT(ROWS(C$2:C2)-1,3)*3))-(INDEX($P$2:$P$945,1+QUOTIENT(ROWS(P$2:P2)-1,3)*3)) ) ^2 +(  (INDEX($D$2:$D$945,1+QUOTIENT(ROWS(D$2:D2)-1,3)*3))-(INDEX($Q$2:$Q$945,1+QUOTIENT(ROWS(Q$2:Q2)-1,3)*3)) ) ^2)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution provided below. The idea is that once your data are in R, you (edit) keep! rows iff they meet 2 criteria. First, the `Surpass` column has to contain the word "blue" in it, which is done with the `grepl` function. Second, the distance must below a certain threshold (set arbitrarily by `thresh`.

```
fakeData=data.frame(Surpass=c('blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue'),
           distance=c(1,2,5,3), num=c(90,10,9,4))  

#thresh is your distance threshold
thresh = 2
fakeDataNoBlue = fakeData[which(grepl('blue', fakeData$Surpass) 
                  & fakeData$distance < thresh),]
```

There's probably also a quick `dplyr` solution using `filter`, but I haven't fully explored the functionality there. Also, I may be a bit confused on if you also want to keep the other colors. If so, that's the same as saying you want to remove the blue ones exceeding a certain distance threshold, which you would just do a `-which` command, and turn the `<` operator into a `>` operator.

Comment: `filter(fakeData, Surpass != 'blue' | distance > thresh)` is the dplyr solution to keep most of the data while tossing out the blues that have too big of a distance. 
But I guess you cobbled something together with Excel. Typing those words felt more than a little wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Would be easier with a reproducible example, but here's a (hacky) `plyr` solution:

```
filterframe<-function(df,threshold){
  df$grouper<-rep(seq(from=1,to=6),nrow(df)/6)
  dataout<-df%>%group_by(grouper)%>%summarise(keep=.[[1]]$distance_to_midpoint<threshold)
  dataout[dataout$keep,]
}

filterframe(mydata)
```